# How can I add a new buildTypes on cordova android app?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova to build an android application and I need to support three environment `debug`, `test` and `prod`. I am thinking to add buildTypes for these three env and give a different file name for each APK from each buildType.

Below is the command I used to build the APK:

```
cordova build android --release --buildType=test --buildConfig=./build.json

cordova build android --debug --buildType=debug --buildConfig=./build.json
cordova build android --release --buildType=prod --buildConfig=./build.json
```

blow is the configuration I used in `build-extra.gradle` to rename the APK name:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    System.out.println(variant.getBuildType().getName())
                    if (variant.getName().equals("release")) {
                        outputFileName = "myapp-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                    } else if (variant.getName().equals("test")) {
                        outputFileName = "myapp-test.apk"
                    } else {
                        outputFileName = "myapp-debug.apk"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the the `test` and `prod` buildType is never picked up. I can't see `myapp-test.apk` is built. I printed the build type name in `build-extra.gradle` but it doesn't show `test` and `prod`. It only shows `debug` and `release`. How can I find the customised buildType in cordova build process?